# If I want to change the content displayed on the dashboard interface, what should I do？

Tags: kubernetes

If I want to change the content displayed on the dashboard interface, what should I do? For example, I want to remove the jobs option from the menu bar on the left. That doesn't mean I want to do it, just want to know the way. Thank you.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'dashboard interface'?

Comment: kubernetes-dashboard, This is its website: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard. The dashboard interface mean dashboard Web UI.

Comment: did you read the document, does it support customization?

Comment: Support customized. Is there only one way? I can find the source code of the front end on the website, can I modify the front-end source code, remake it into an image, and then deploy it?

Comment: k8s is open source, and sure you can fork and build your own. but i doubt it is that easy.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.